# Avoid submenu from disappearing quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, dhtml

All,

How do I modify the javascript behind the following menu to make sure the menu items don't disappear  so fast when they are no longer hovered? I want the submenus to wait for atleast 2 seconds on the screen before they disappear.

http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/dropdown-menu/index.html

The Javascript behind the html looks like this:

```
var menu=function(){
    var t=0,z=50,s=6,a;
    function dd(n){this.n=n; this.h=[]; this.c=[]}
    dd.prototype.init=function(p,c){
        a=c; var w=document.getElementById(p), s=w.getElementsByTagName('ul'), 
                     l=s.length, i=0;
        for(i;i<l;i++){
            var h=s[i].parentNode; this.h[i]=h; this.c[i]=s[i];
            h.onmouseover=new Function(this.n+'.st('+i+',true)');
            h.onmouseout=new Function(this.n+'.st('+i+')');
        }
    }
    dd.prototype.st=function(x,f){
        var c=this.c[x], h=this.h[x], p=h.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        clearInterval(c.t); c.style.overflow='hidden';
        if(f){
            p.className+=' '+a;
            if(!c.mh){c.style.display='block'; c.style.height=''; 
                       c.mh=c.offsetHeight; c.style.height=0}
            if(c.mh==c.offsetHeight){c.style.overflow='visible'}
            else{c.style.zIndex=z; z++; c.t=setInterval(function(){sl(c,1)},t)}
        }else{p.className=p.className.replace(a,''); 
                   c.t=setInterval(function(){sl(c,-1)},t)}
    }
    function sl(c,f){
        var h=c.offsetHeight;
        if((h<=0&&f!=1)||(h>=c.mh&&f==1)){
            if(f==1){c.style.filter=''; c.style.opacity=1; 
                       c.style.overflow='visible'}
            clearInterval(c.t); return
        }
        var d=(f==1)?Math.ceil((c.mh-h)/s):Math.ceil(h/s), o=h/c.mh;
        c.style.opacity=o; c.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+(o*100)+')';
        c.style.height=h+(d*f)+'px'
    }
    return{dd:dd}
}();
```

Comment: Please provide some sample code. Otherwise, it's really difficult to suggest anything......

Comment: There is a good reason why they disappear so fast.

Comment: Two seconds is a *long* time in UI-land. My menus stay open for 7/10ths of a second (700 milliseconds) after the mouse leaves and even that feels too long sometimes, so we also added click-to-dismiss. Clicking outside the menu makes it disappear immediately.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(

    function(){

        // here is  you code for disappear menu

    }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's delay function before hiding the menu.

I saw your code. You're using onmouseout event. Inside that event, you can wait for 2 seconds, then hiding the dropped down menu:

```
$('#menu').hover(function () {
     // Mouse entered.
}, function () {
     // Mouse left (out)
     $(this).delay(2000).hide();
});
```

Comment: where do i adjust this inside the js?

Comment: Your plugin doesn't use jQuery, and there is no `delay` function built into JavaScript. There are many ways to imitate that and one of'em is setTimeout.

Comment: I understand that. Just wasn't sure which function in the above JS code to use the setTimeout for. It would be helpful if you can try it out locally. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good candidate for [hoverintent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).